# Passing Excel rows as an array to autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

In sheet1, I have 4 rows with header "Company Name" with values as "Google", "Microsoft",Yahoo"
now in sheet2 I need to set a filter with these 3 values

```
ActiveSheet.Range(A1:AC20).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Google", "Microsoft","Yahoo"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But now I want it to be dynamic so that I will create an array from the range in sheet1 with company names, and this list is passed in sheet2 for filtering.

Something like

```
comp_name_array = Range(A1:A5)
```

this will create array with all company names and then pass this array in

```
ActiveSheet.Range(A1:AC20).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(comp_name_array), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose that range to make a 1D array. THen because the variable is an array, you don't need the `Array()` function:

```
comp_name_array = Application.Transpose(Range(A1:A5).Value)
ActiveSheet.Range(A1:AC20).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=comp_name_array, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```